# Laravel 4.1 - passing resource ID from form <select> to controller method?

Tags: php, forms, laravel-4

Sorry if this is a stupid question. I'm very new to laravel / MVC, and haven't had enough coffee today, so I wouldn't be surprised if the answer is sitting right in front of me. :)

**background**: I have a form with a select. The form is used to delete a "user" and all their associated resources from the database. The `<select>` is populated with unique ID's. on form submit, I would like to send a `DELETE` request to my Controller class, passing in the selected ID for deletion.

I can't figure out how to pass in the ID from the select, into the form. How do I make it so that when you select (for example) ID `1` in the drop down, that is passed into my resource routing on the form?

Here's some code:

```
{{ Form::open(array(
  'url'   =>'/clients',
  'method'=>'delete',
  'name'  =>'delClient',
  'role'  =>'form',
  'class' =>'form-horizontal')) }}

<h4>Please select the client you would like to delete:</h4>

  {{ 
    Form::selectField('delClientSelect', 'Client: ', array(
      0=>'-- Select Client --')+$clientsList) 
  }}

   {{ 
      Form::submit('Delete Selected', array(
        'class'    => 'btn btn-danger confDelClient',
        'data-role'=> 'delete'
      )) 
    }}    
{{ Form::close() }}
```

Everything I read online says that you pass the id into the Form `'url'` attribute, i.e:

```
{{
 Form::open(array('url'=>'/clients/{id}'))
}}
```

but, as the ID is coming from the `<select>`, I'm not sure what the proper method is for getting the ID into my routing.

Thanks for any help!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are using a resource controller where you must use the `DELETE` verb to delete a record, then I would use jQuery to update the form URL/action to `'url'=>'/clients/{id}'` as you stated.
Basically, on form submit (with jQuery that's `$('form').submit()`) you can append the ID from the select field to the forms url/action.

If you aren't using a resource controller, I would use the `POST` method, grab the ID from the select using `Input::all()` or `Input::get()` and then make your database call to delete the records from the database.

Comment: I am using a resource controller, sorry if I didn't make that clear. :) I was aware I could append the ID with jQuery but I didn't feel that was best practice, is there any way to do it by Laravel only? Thank you for your help.

Comment: Usually you are using a resource controller to handle 1 resource (in your case 1 user). Each route (store, create, show, edit, etc) deals with one resource. I would say having a select field to select one user to delete doesnt really follow that practice.

Normally, you have a show page to show that 1 user. On that page, you would have a delete link with a route to the destroy/delete action.

Comment: I see -- I'm still only manipulating one user, you just get to select which user; does that not follow the practice? Do you think in this scenario I would be better off just using plain POST and writing my own method instead of relying on the resource controller defaults? Thanks!

Comment: Well its totally up to you. You should have a page where you are manipulating only one user using the show action (/resource/{resource}). You should select a user (from a table), and then it brings you to the show page. On that show page, you would have the delete action. From what I understand, you are trying to delete the user directly from the select form. If you want to do that, then Id suggest using POST

Comment: Yeah this is essentially for an "admin" utility, where they can manage  and delete other users. I will go about implementing a POST method. Thanks for your help!